# Hosting my google-apps in own domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a stand alone app with apps script in google. I will like to host the app in a sub domain.
eg. myapp.mysitedomain.com is it possible? and if possible how should I do it?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For google sites, you can change the domain name.
ex : https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/googleapps/google_sites.htm

but for you application , i think it's not possible.
If you use google app script or Google app engine , you can't change the domain.